# SSIS Data Viewer not displaying correctly

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Would like to seek your help regarding a Data Viewer bug. I am performing a simple Extract and Load with Data Viewer enabled. However when run the Data Viewer screen did show up, but it displayed a blank screen (like when an app is not responding) without any visible data or actionable buttons - Play, Detach, Copy Data...

I tried to disable and re-enable Data Viewer multiple times but still not working.

Any idea what the cause is ?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a scenario how we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Visual Studio in safe mode using the following command:

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

If it works, then there are some add-ins that are causing this issue.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I try to reinstall visual studio and the add-ins again and it works properly now.

Comment: @Tom then you should write your own answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot guys ! Finally  the fix is to reinstall visual studio and the add-ins again.